# Need help for creating function and removing function in linkedlist with respect to my code? New to C programming

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode 

{

   void *data;

   struct LinkedListNode *next;

}LinkedListNode;

typedef struct 

{

   LinkedListNode *head;

}LinkedList;


LinkedList *createLinkedList()

{

  LinkedList *ll = (LinkedList *) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList))

  ll->head = NULL;

  return ll;

}

void insertFirst (LinkedList *list, void *data)

{

     Cannot create this function ? 
  
}

void removeFirst(LinkedList *list)

{

     Cannot create this function?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you with your `insertFirst` function.

```
void insertFirst(LinkedList *list, void *data)
{
    LinkedListNode *node = NULL;

    node = malloc(sizeof *node); /* allocate a new node */

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        /* handle oom */
    }

    node->data = data; /* save the data */
    node->next = list->head; /* point the next node to head */
    
    list->head = node; /* set head to the node we just created */

    return;
}
```

Comment: what about remove first Mr.alex ?

Comment: @lupin `removeFirst` should be pretty easy to implement, just hold a tmp node for the first element, point `head->list`, to `head->list->next` and free the tmp node...

Comment: can you edit this in a code so I can be fully aware what are you trying to say? Mr.alex

Answer (score 1):

The both functions, `insertFirst` and `removeFirst`, should have the return type `int` to report to the user of the functions whether their actions were successful.

For example

```
int insertFirst ( LinkedList *list, void *data )
{
    LinkedListNode *node = malloc( sizeof( LinkedListNode ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = list->head;
        list->head = node;
    }

    return success;
}


int removeFirst( LinkedList *list )
{
    int success = list->head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        LinkedListNode *node = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        
        free( node->data );
        free( node );
    }

    return success;
}
```

I assume that the pointer `data` used in the function `insertFirst` points to a dynamically allocated object. Otherwise in the function `removeFirst` you need to remove the statement

```
free( node->data );
```

Comment: `if (success)`, what if `failure`, you'll still `return success`.

Comment: @alex01011 You are right. success either can have the logical true value (1 ) or logical false value (0).

Comment: Ahhh, totally missed that, got confused by the name.